# Does such a function exist: $\left|f(x) - f(x+1)\right| \ge {1\over x+1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Does a function $f(x)$ exist such that $\left|f(x) - f(x+1)\right| \ge {1\over x+1}$ where the range of the function does not extend infinitely in the positive direction. If not why?

Comment: There are finite lengthed intervals such that $1\ge \dfrac{1}{x+1}$, so $f(x)=x$, defined on those intervals, works.

Comment: It must be unbounded near $x=-1$

Comment: $f(x)=(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}$

Comment: No increasing function (on $\mathbb{R}_+$) like that exist since $f(N+1) - f(1) = \sum_{x=1}^N f(x+1)-f(x) \geq \sum_{x=1}^N \frac{1}{x+1}$ which contradicts that $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Do you intend for the function to be continuous?  It's not stated, but the question is more interesting with that hypothesis.  (See @Winther's comment above.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like: $f(x)$ is defined for $x \ge 2$, with
$f(x) = 0$ if $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is even, and $f(x) = 2$ for $\lfloor x \rfloor$ odd.  Then floors of $x$ and $x+1$ differ in parity, so one of them is $0$ and the other is $2$, and thus we have
$$
|f(x)-f(x+1)| = 2 > \frac{1}{x+1}
$$
The range of this function is $\{0,2\}$, and is bounded.

Comment: I see Michael beat me to this.